# When evaluating a C expression where are the temporary results stored?

Tags: c

Following is the program that raised the mentioned doubt for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { 
    int g = 300000*300000/300000;
    printf("%d",g);
    return 0;
}
```

When the `*` is evaluated the result would be `90000000000`. Then is divided by `300000`.
I expected the first expression result to be stored somewhere then divided by `300000`. So output would be `300000`.

But it is giving me `-647`.
Does this mean it is evaluated as :

```
g = 300000*300000;
g = g / 300000;
```

Comment: In this case it's probably computed by the compiler, so it's basically equivalent to `g =  -647`

Comment: Use appropriate data types. An int cannot hold that big a value.

Comment: Yes it is integer overflow,does that mean the each expression result is stored one by one to the g? like : g = 300000*300000; g = g / 300000;

Comment: @ZoomIn No, not necessarily. When it's fully compiled, those intermediate values can be anywhere (register, memory...). Which may or may not be the same place as `g`.

Comment: Or even nowhere at all due to compile time constant evaluation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless of where it's stored, it's still of type `int`. Assuming `int` is 32-bits on your machine, you're getting integer overflow with `300000*300000`.

```
300000*300000 -> 90000000000 -> -194313216  (integer overflow)
-194313216 / 300000 -> -647
```

Basically, temporaries (or intermediates) don't magically allow you to get around overflow.

---

*Note that signed integer overflow is technically undefined behavior. But in this case it happens to wrap-around the way you'd expect.

Comment: I am curious, how did you calculate the number `-194313216`?

Comment: `90000000000 % 2^32 = 4100654080` But that is still beyond the range of 32-bit signed integer. So `4100654080 - 2^32 = -194313216`.

Comment: @noMAD subtract 4294967296 until the result is in the range of `int`.

Comment: @noMAD: 90000000000 = 0x14`F46B0400, 0xF46B0400 = -194313216.

Comment: @Alex: I don't get it. The first one is the Hex of `90000000000`. What the other hex and how did you get it?

Comment: @noMAD You chop off the upper hex-digits that don't fit.

Answer (score 2):

Both `3000000` are of type `int`, so the result is tried to be matched into an int as well. And that leads to a register overflow. The `/ 300000` afterwards doesn't help any longer.

You might use `3000000ll` for one of the factors to make it a `long long`.